# How to disable old TLS versions in Windows?

Tags: ssl, windows-11, internet-connection, https, tls

Using Windows 11, no server or IIS, just want to disable old TLS versions of my personal computer so no connection over those versions can be made, even if that means some connections will fail.

I want to completely disable TLS v1, TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.2.

I tried the Internet options advanced settings, but they have no effect on anything as far as I can tell, and I don't know why they are even there.

all the articles I read online is either about Windows Server or IIS.

I'm using Microsoft Edge browser.

I want to disable those old TLS versions in a way that I don't see any TLS connection other than TLS v1.3 in Wireshark.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this, but note that TLS 1.2 is not considered insecure (assuming the right ciphers are used).

Comment: Hi, for TLS 1.2 I mainly want to test how I will be affected if I disable it and make it permanent if it doesn't break important parts of the OS but definitely want to disable TLS 1 and TLS 1.1 permanently no matter what.

Comment: I think *most* sites are still on 1.2 - I tried setting my site 1.3 only and it broke in some platforms

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Hi, really interested to know which platforms didn't accept TLS 1.3 and whether the browser was the barrier or the OS.

Comment: Does [Disable Enable TLS 1.0 And 1.1 For Internet Explorer EdgeHTML HTMD Blog](https://www.anoopcnair.com/disable-enable-tls-1-0-1-1-internet-explorer-ie/) answer your question?

Comment: Was android client apps for things strangely enough.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for that, the page you linked led me to find a successful solution for Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

This still doesn't fully satisfy my needs and it's incomplete, there are valuable info in the comments section down below, **if you have better answer please post them.**

---

So far only found a way to disable the TLS versions in browser, but still not system wide, I still see connections being made over insecure TLS v1 and TLS v1.1 from time to time in Wireshark with no way to block them, mostly initiated by programs I installed.

For Microsoft Edge, TLS v1 and TLS v1.1 are already disabled by default, in order to disable TLS v1.2, run this in an elevated PowerShell:

```
$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\TLSCipherSuiteDenyList\'  
$Name         = '1'  
$Value        = '0xC02B' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType string -Force


$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\TLSCipherSuiteDenyList\'  
$Name         = '2'  
$Value        = '0xC02F' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType string -Force



$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\TLSCipherSuiteDenyList\'  
$Name         = '3'  
$Value        = '0xC02C' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType string -Force


$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\TLSCipherSuiteDenyList\'  
$Name         = '4'  
$Value        = '0xC030' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType string -Force


$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\TLSCipherSuiteDenyList\'  
$Name         = '5'  
$Value        = '0xCCA9' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType string -Force


$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\TLSCipherSuiteDenyList\'  
$Name         = '6'  
$Value        = '0xCCA8' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType string -Force


$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\TLSCipherSuiteDenyList\'  
$Name         = '7'  
$Value        = '0x009E' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType string -Force



$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\TLSCipherSuiteDenyList\'  
$Name         = '8'  
$Value        = '0x009F' 
If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {   New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force | Out-Null } 
New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -PropertyType string -Force
```

Used these 2 resources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#tlsciphersuitedenylist

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS

Still looking for a way to do the same for the entire OS.

**UPDATE:** in Windows, disabled all cipher suits and only kept those that belong to TLS v1.3

```
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384


disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA384
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256


disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384



Enable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Enable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
# Added in Windows 11 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-11
Enable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

This caused some websites that supported both TLS 1.3 and 1.2 use 1.3 instead, prior to this change they kept using 1.2.

in Wireshark though, this didn't stop TLS 1.1 and 1.2 from showing up, but their cipher suits are being enforced correctly, which is weird for me because I thought cipher suits used by TLS v1.3 can't be used by older TLS versions.

Comment: That only disables them for Edge, Chrome and Firefox, could still use them. Additionally, there isn’t a way to prevent an application, from using say TLS 1.2 if there’s no option within the application settings

Comment: @Ramhound I made more progress but need some info if you could provide please, seems like it's not as easy as specifying a TLS version and that gets automatically disabled, but we have the ability to disable cipher suits that are used by TLS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/disable-tlsciphersuite?source=recommendations&view=windowsserver2022-ps

so even though https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS mentions only 3 cipher suits for TLS 1.3 and doesn't say older TLS versions can utilize them, I see in Wireshark that TLS 1.2 and 1.1 are using them! any idea?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that `disable-TlsCipherSuite` only applies to Microsoft Edge, and those commands simply set the registry keys you already have modified.

Comment: @Ramhound Then why after removing all of them 
except TLS 1.3 ciphers suits, OneDrive couldn't connect and Sticky Notes app couldn't sync? not to mention that there isn't any word about "Edge" in that Microsoft Docs page.

Comment: @Ramhound+ rather, registry and posh settings only affect things _that use schannel_: that includes Edge and IIS, and posh and vbscript(!), I'd expect but can't verify Outlook, the curl.exe supplied by Microsoft, and some more as noted by OP, but not Chrome, Firefox, other programs that use portable stacks like Java nodejs python php, and anything in wsl.

Comment: OP: there are actually 5 ciphersuites in 1.3, but Mozilla only recommends and Win11 only implements 3; they are indeed unusable in lower protocols and the lower suites unusable in 1.3, but a 1.3-capable client can, and all I know of at present do, _offer_ in the ClientHello both 1.3 and at least 1.2 (sometimes lower) with a ciphersuite list that includes both types; it is the ServerHello, only, that must select one version and one ciphersuite compatible with it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you, that made things much clearer, could you point me to some reading material that's about the portable stack that you talked about? want to know what they are exactly.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_implementations#Portability_concerns for a start. OpenSSL/SSLeay (plus forks LibreSSL and BoringSSL), NSS and GnuTLS are written in C, and JSSE and BouncyCastle in Java, and are widely available and used on at least all Linux (usually other Unix also) and Windows.  MbedTLS/PolarSSL Wolf/CyaSSL and [BearSSL](https://bearssl.org) (omitted from wikipedia but its author Thomas Pornin is a big contributor to crypto.SX and security.SX) are also portable but less widely used. There are others that you probably won't encounter.